# Azure API App not recognizing Swagger definition

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, swagger, azure-api-apps

I'm trying out Azure's API App service, and I have a valid Swagger schema exposed for the service to consume, following the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/#download-and-inspect-code-for-a-nodejs-api-app). I can retrieve the Swagger schema at its endpoint both on my local server and once the API App is deployed, and I've updated my web.config file to include the application/json MIME type. My apiapp.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "id": "apiapp.dlxdev",
  "namespace": "microsoft.com",
  "gateway": "/* gateway, copied from Azure portal */",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "title": "DLX API App (Dev)",
  "summary": "The developer version of the DLX API App.",
  "author": "Daniel W. Hieber",
  "endpoints": {
    "apiDefinition": "/api.json",
    "status": null
  }
}
```

Even though my endpoint is defined as `/api.json`, when I go to the API Definition blade in the Azure Portal, it says `Failed to get metadata for 'apiApp.dlxDev' from endpoint '/swagger/docs/v1': Failed status code: 'NotFound'. Response Body: 'Not Found'.`. It seems as though Azure is still looking for my Swagger file at the default `/swagger/docs/v1` endpoint rather than the `/api.json` endpoint I specified.

I've also tried creating a `metadata` folder and placing my Swagger schema there (renaming it to `apiDefinition.swagger.json`, following the documentation), and didn't have any luck with that either.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Why isn't Azure detecting the endpoint for my Swagger schema?

## UPDATE 1

Now I receive the following error in the API Definition blade: `#/definitions/: Cannot determine schema of data definition named ''`. This doesn't appear to be a problem with the Swagger schema itself, since all of my schema references are formatted correctly, and the schema itself is valid.

## UPDATE 2

One thing that I needed to do was restart the gateway under which my API app was being hosted. Restarting the gateway is what caused the error message to change. So I think the app is recognizing my Swagger schema now. But I'm still not sure why I'm getting the 'Cannot determine schema' error, since my schema is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I receive the following error in the API Definition blade: >#/definitions/: Cannot determine schema of data definition named ''. This >doesn't appear to be a problem with the Swagger schema itself, since all of my >schema references are formatted correctly, and the schema itself is valid.

I believe Azure requires a default response defined in swagger for every operation.  Perhaps double check that every operation has a default response and every response has a schema property which resolves to a valid schema in the definitions section.

Like:

```
"paths": {
    "/Categories": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Categories"
        ],
        ...
        ],
        ...
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "EntitySet Categories",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/NorthwindAPI.Models.Category"
    }
  },
  "default": {
    "description": "Unexpected error",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/_Error"
    }
  }
},
...
"definitions": {
"NorthwindAPI.Models.Category": {
    "properties": {
        "CategoryID": {
          "format": "int32",
          "description": "CategoryID",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "CategoryName": {
          "description": "CategoryName",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Description": {
          "description": "Description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Picture": {
          "description": "Picture",
          "type": "string"
        }
    }
},
"_Error": {
    "properties": {
        "error": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/_InError"
        }
    }
},
```

HTH,
Josh

Comment: Just FYI, I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I will soon and I'll post here whether it worked. Appreciate the reply!